# How to get Thread Safe in DAO design?

Tags: java, thread-safety, dao

To my understanding it is possible with this code that when changing a user role another user can change the same role and always wins the last. It would even be possible for us to store parts of one and parts of the other. This is possible due to the 3 queries in the DAO. I would like to get "ThreadSafe" that during a change not another user can make a change or it will be detected that someone changed it before.

My idea was to change the method in the RoleManager.

Idea:

```
public interface RoleManager {
static synchronized void EditRole(UserRoleBO editedObjet, UserRoleBO nonEditedObject);
```

This does not work with this type of design(with a  interface).

My Question:

Is there an elegant way to solve the problem without changing the
        design?

Addition Note:

Tell me if i have big mistakes in my code.

Manager:

```
public class RoleManagerImpl implements RoleManager {

    @Override
    public void editRole(UserRoleBO editedObjet, UserRoleBO nonEditedObject) {
        EditUserRole editUserRole = EditUserRole.Factory.createEditUserRole(nonEditedObject);
        boolean hasChangedBeforeInDB = editUserRole.detectChanges();
        if (hasChangedBeforeInDB) {
            throw new ManagerException(ManagerException.TYPE.HASCHANGEDBEFOREINDB, null);
        }
        RoleDAO roleDAO = new RoleDAOImpl();
        roleDAO.editRole(editedObjet);
    }
}
```

DAO:

```
    @Override
    public int editRole(UserRoleBO role) {
        Connection conn = null;
        int status;
        try  {
            //Set up connection
            conn = ConnectionPool.getInstance().acquire();
            DSLContext create = DSL.using(conn, SQLDialect.MARIADB);

            //sql processing and return
            status = create.executeUpdate(role.getRole());
            EditUserRole editUserRole = EditUserRole.Factory.createEditUserRole(role);
            editUserRole.detectChanges();
            addPermission(editUserRole.getAddlist(), role.getRole());
            deletePermissions(editUserRole.getDeleteList(), role.getRole());        
        } 
        // Error handling sql
        catch (MappingException e) {
            throw new DAOException(DAOException.TYPE.MAPPINGEXCEPTION, e);
        } 
        catch (DataAccessException e) {
            throw new DAOException(DAOException.TYPE.DATAACCESSEXECPTION, e);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            throw new DAOException(DAOException.TYPE.UNKOWNEXCEPTION, e);
        } finally {
            //Connection release handling
            try{
                if(conn != null) {
                    ConnectionPool.getInstance().release(conn);
                }
            }
            // Error handling connection
            catch (DataAccessException e) {
                throw new DAOException(DAOException.TYPE.RELEASECONNECTIONEXCEPTION, e);
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                throw new DAOException(DAOException.TYPE.UNKOWNRELEASECONNECTIONEXCEPTION, e);
            }  
        }
        //Return result
        return status;
    }
```

Thanks for helping.

Comment: I don&#39;t think method synchronization is applicable here. You usually use synchronization when you are dealing with shared object in memory but in your case you are dealing with shared data stored in database. You most likely need to use database locking and transactions.
You need to realize that your application can have more than one instance running in different  application container instances with their own JVM.

Comment: @tsolakp Many thanks. You are completely right. There can be Multiple servers running the application in their own JVM. You gave me the necessary thought. I will post a solution which works when assuming that there is only one database.

Answer (score 0):

this is just a possible answer. In my case, i use jooq and a mariadb.

With the assumption that we only have one central database this solution works. In a cluster, there is always the problem of the split brain.

What happens is that I lock the rows. So if the next thread tries to lock this he must wait. If it is allowed to continue, the exception HASCHANGEDBEFOREINDB is thrown.

Take care u have to commit or rollback to end the lock.

EditRole:

```
@Override
    public int editRole(UserRoleBO editedRole ,UserRoleBO nonEditedRole) throws SQLException {
        Connection conn = null;
        int status;
        try  {
            //Set up connection
            conn = ConnectionPool.getInstance().acquire();
            conn.setAutoCommit(false);
            DSLContext create = DSL.using(conn, SQLDialect.MARIADB);

            //lock rows
            lockRowsOf(editedRole, conn);


            EditUserRole editUserRole = EditUserRole.Factory.createEditUserRole(nonEditedRole);
            boolean hasChangedBeforeInDB = editUserRole.detectChanges();
            if (hasChangedBeforeInDB) {
                throw new DAOException(DAOException.TYPE.HASCHANGEDBEFOREINDB, null);
            }


            EditUserRole editUserRole2 = EditUserRole.Factory.createEditUserRole(editedRole);
            editUserRole2.detectChanges();


            //sql processing and return
            status = create.executeUpdate(editedRole.getRole());

            addPermission(editUserRole2.getAddlist(), editedRole.getRole().getId(), conn);
            deletePermissions(editUserRole2.getDeleteList(), editedRole.getRole(), conn);  
            conn.commit();
        } 
        // Error handling sql
        catch (MappingException e) {
            conn.rollback();
            throw new DAOException(DAOException.TYPE.MAPPINGEXCEPTION, e);
        } 
        catch (DataAccessException e) {
            conn.rollback();
            throw new DAOException(DAOException.TYPE.DATAACCESSEXECPTION, e);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            conn.rollback();
            throw new DAOException(DAOException.TYPE.UNKOWNEXCEPTION, e);
        } finally {
            //Connection release handling
            try{
                if(conn != null) {
                    conn.setAutoCommit(true);
                    ConnectionPool.getInstance().release(conn);
                }
            }
            // Error handling connection
            catch (DataAccessException e) {
                throw new DAOException(DAOException.TYPE.RELEASECONNECTIONEXCEPTION, e);
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                throw new DAOException(DAOException.TYPE.UNKOWNRELEASECONNECTIONEXCEPTION, e);
            }  
        }
        //Return result
        return status;
    }
```

Lock:

```
 @Override
        public void lockRowsOf(UserRoleBO role, Connection conn) {
            int status;
            try  {
                DSLContext create = DSL.using(conn, SQLDialect.MARIADB);
                //sql processing and return
                status = create.select()
                        .from(AUTH_ROLE)
                        .where(AUTH_ROLE.ID.eq(role.getRole().getId()))
                        .forUpdate().execute();
                status = create.select()
                        .from(AUTH_ROLE_PERMISSION)
                        .where(AUTH_ROLE_PERMISSION.ROLE_ID.eq(role.getRole().getId()))
                        .forUpdate().execute();
            } 
            // Error handling sql
            catch (MappingException e) {
                throw new DAOException(DAOException.TYPE.MAPPINGEXCEPTION, e);
            } 
            catch (DataAccessException e) {
                throw new DAOException(DAOException.TYPE.DATAACCESSEXECPTION, e);
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                throw new DAOException(DAOException.TYPE.UNKOWNEXCEPTION, e);
            } finally {
                //Connection will still needed to buffer the delete and insert
            }
        }
```